# groovy design pattern for forms

Tags: groovy

I really like the groovy language but I believe my java experience is leading me to a path where I don't use groovys fully potential.

I have a scenario where a groovy object (Master.groovy) sends some json-data to some view that creates a form out of this data. Then the user can submit this form and Master.groovy receives it as json-data again.

Master.groovy can access a pool of different form descriptions (formDesc1, formDesc2, etc.) which it choses from when sending the json to the view. When the user returns the json data - Master.groovy will then pass it over to e.g. formDesc1 to validate it.

This is how it looks with code:

Master.groovy

```
class Master {

    FormDesc[] formDescs = [new FormDesc1(), new FormDesc2(), new FormDesc2()]


    def getJSONform(Integer formId){
        return formDescs[formId].getForm()
    }

    def validateForm(Integer formId, def data) {
        return formDescs[formId].validate(data)
    }
}
```

FormDesc1.groovy

```
class FormDesc1 extends FormDesc {
    static String name = "alias"
    FormDesc1 (){
        form.add(new InputElement(name:name, type:"text"))
        form.add(new TextArea(name:"msg", rows:"12", cols:"12"))
    }


    @Override
    def validate(data){
        errors = []
        if(data.get(name)["value"] != "form1")
            errors.add("name not allowed")

        return errors
    }
}
```

FormDesc2.groovy

```
class FormDesc2 extends FormDesc {
    static String name = "alias"
    FormDesc1 (){
        form.add(new InputElement(name:name, type:"text"))
        form.add(new TextArea(name:"msg", rows:"12", cols:"12"))
    }


    @Override
    def validate(data){
        errors = []
        if(data.get(name)["value"] != "form1")
            errors.add("name not allowed")

        return errors
    }
}
```

There can be many forms in the package /forms and to load all of them in the memory seems very unnecessary. And it would be much nicer if the formDesc consisted of json-data that represented the form and then only has the method validate. E.g:

FormDescUltimate.groovy

```
class FormDescUltimate extends FormDesc {
    form = loadJSONFile("formDescUltimate.json")

    @Override
    def validate(data){
        errors = []
        if(data.get("alias")["value"] != "form1")
            errors.add("name not allowed")

        return errors
    }
}
```

formDescUltimate.json

```
{
    'formId' : 'ultimate_form',
    'elements': [
        {'InputElement' : {'name': 'alias', 'type':'text'}},
        {'TextArea' : {'name': 'msg', 'rows':'12', 'cols':'12'}}
    ]
}
```

Is it possible to achieve this nicely with groovy, or is there any better design to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance and sorry for the long post!

Comment: +1 for "I believe my java experience is leading me to a path where I don't use groovys fully potential" :-)

Comment: If you would've used Grails you'd be able to accomplish this easily with Command objects [link](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/single.html#commandObjects). not sure if you have that in pure Groovy tho.

Comment: As a matter of fact I'm using Grails :) but I would need the user to only define some html form elements e.g: input, textarea, select, option. So is it possible to do this in a controller object like this?

  `class form1 extends Validateable {
  String name
  static constraints = {
   name (blank:false, element:"input", type:"text")
  }
 }`

And how would I define a list with many options in a controller object?
Thanks!

Comment: Edit: command objects and not controllers